# extracting table elements with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I'd like to use CasperJS to extract successive (inner) HTML fields from a table into a list.  I know it's easy to extract successive *element attributes* from a table, but I can't figure out how to extract successive HTML fields.

To demonstrate, here's a simple HTML table:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td name="a">1</td><td>hop</td></tr>
        <tr><td name="b">2</td><td>skip</td></tr>
        <tr><td name="c">3</td><td>jump</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's a complete casper program to extract bits from the table:

```
"use strict";
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('file:///tmp/casper-so.html');

// I want to print the list '["a", "b", "c"]'
casper.then(function a1() {
    var names = casper.getElementsAttribute('table tr td[name]', 'name');
    // prints ["a", "b", "c"] as desired...
    console.log(JSON.stringify(names, null, 2));
});

// I want to print the list '["hop", "skip", "jump"]'
casper.then(function a2() {
    var verbs = ???;
    // What should go on the previous line in order to print 
    // ["hop", "skip", "jump"]?
    console.log(JSON.stringify(verbs, null, 2));
});

casper.run();
```

As commented in the code, I know how to extract all the td[name] fields using `casper.getElementsAttribute()`.  But I haven't figured out a straightforward way to extract the inner HTML from a given column in the table.  Any pointers?

*Aside: What I've been doing is extracting elements one at a time, iterating with an index, using CSS that looks like `table tr:nth-child(' + index + ') td:nth-child(2)`, but that feels rather tortured.  I'm hoping to find something simpler.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution, cribbed heavily from casper's definition of getElementsAttribute():

```
// print the list '["hop", "skip", "jump"]'
casper.then(function a2() {
    var verbs = casper.evaluate(function () {
        return [].map.call(__utils__.findAll('table tr td:nth-child(2)'), function (e) { return e.innerHTML; });
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(verbs, null, 2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to get the td info object, and then the text from the object:

```
//get hop - 2nd td in DOM
var tdObject = this.getElementInfo('tr td:nth-of-type(2)');
tdTwoObjectText = tdObject.text.trim();

//get skip - 4th td in DOM
var tdObject = this.getElementInfo('tr td:nth-of-type(4)');
tdFourObjectText = tdObject.text.trim();

//get jump - 6th td in DOM
var tdObject = this.getElementInfo('tr td:nth-of-type(6)');
tdSixObjectText = tdObject.text.trim();
```